# How to generate APK file by Expo's Bare workflow but using previous expo's Managed workflow JKS file

Tags: android, react-native

I have Project which is previously running great on Expo. But due to native Utube experience i have to eject. Now i am in **bare workflow** and my problem is how to generate APK using the same **jks file, keyAlias** etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Got it. I just need to change extension **jks** to **keystore**.

Comment: Please, can you explain more in another answer? How exactly to generate the APK?

Answer (score 1):

You have to export keystore from existing expo apk/project:

```
expo fetch:android:keystore
```